# ACapture - Payment Gateway service not working in Java 7

Tags: payment, gateway

Recently I tried to integrate Acapture processor gateway with my application. My application running on Java version 1.7. I got timeout exception for Acapture payment request:

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [20000 milliseconds]

But I got response on Java 1.6 and 1.8. It's not working on Java 1.7.

Java Version 1.7

Request:

```
{ "action":"payment",
  "header":{"businessId":"877777","additionalProperties":{}},
  "body":{"transaction":{"trackingCode":"4381-65-0734","type":"SINGLE","brandId":"1010","amount":"52","currencyCode":"USD","countryCode":"US","additionalProperties":{}},
  "card":{"holderName":"Sharon ","number":"4000000000000002","expiryMonth":"02","expiryYear":"2020","cvv":"123","additionalProperties":{}},
  "additionalProperties":{}
},"additionalProperties":{}}
```

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [20000 milliseconds]
>       at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96)
>       at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:58)
>       at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86)
>       at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86)
>       at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:173)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:2803)
>       at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread.blockOn(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:171)
>       at scala.concurrent.Await$.ready(package.scala:86)
>       at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise.await(Promise.scala:134)
>       at play.libs.F$Promise.get(F.java:213)
>       at play.libs.F$Promise.get(F.java:224)
>       at com.kachyng.payment.gateway.acapture.service.AcapturePaymentService.processPaymentService(AcapturePaymentService.java:115)
>       at com.kachyng.payment.gateway.acapture.service.AcapturePaymentService.makePaymentRequest(AcapturePaymentService.java:63)
>       at com.kachyng.processor.ProcessorGateway.process(ProcessorGateway.java:222)
>       at controllers.PaymentGateway.process(PaymentGateway.java:28)
>       at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$9$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(routes_routing.scala:145)
>       at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$9$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(routes_routing.scala:145)
>       at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:193)
>       at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:373)
>       at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:50)
>       at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:63)
>       at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:80)
>       at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:79)
>       at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:425)
>       at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
>       at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

Java version 1.6:

Response :

```
{ "result":"0",
  "description":"Ok",
  "header":{"requestTimestamp":"2016-11-08T07:23:49Z","requestCode":"FES.201.ea00df08-2868-42c5-a792-16c9c24f1651"},
  "body":{"transaction":{"action":"payment","id":"996e7ed3-8a52-4dc4-bc0e-7fc15adb4a70","trackingCode":"7622-31-9702","amount":"5.00","currencyCode":"USD","brandId":"1010","descriptor":"0235.2924.3298 Kachyng CC 3D"},"card":{"firstSixDigits":"400000","lastFourDigits":"0002","expiryMonth":"02","expiryYear":"2020","holderName":"Sharon Jda"}}
}
```

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from Acapture technical support team. According to PCI new regulation Acapture should only support TLS 1.2 only. And Java 7 doesn’t support it. It is a java limitation. Acapture would suggest to use Java 8.